# how to add javascript to a web form in Microsoft Dynamics 365

Tags: javascript, microsoft-dynamics

I am making a web form in Dynamics 365 and am currently trying to figure out, how to add a javascript code to it. Web form is working and is displayed correctly (submit also works), but the problem is in the way javascript code has to be added. I tried following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/marketing/developer/marketing-form-client-side-extensibility

The problem is that I can't get even the basic console.log() to run. I added the code to the form in a script tag in the < head>, like this, but the code gets removed when i inspect the webpage upon load. loader.js, which is needed, loads. Here is the sample code, that I added.

```
<pre>
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log("SHOW ME");
MsCrmMkt.MsCrmFormLoader.on("formLoad", function(event) {
    console.log("formLoad");
})
MsCrmMkt.MsCrmFormLoader.on("formRender", function(event) {
    console.log("formRender");
})
</script>
</pre>
```

Can somebody help me and show me what is the correct way to add JS code to the page?

Thank you

Comment: Are you talking about the crm portals? I see Dynamics Marketing link but not quite sure without seeing some screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Mybe you should give look at [HTML Web References for Dynamics 365](https://crmbook.powerobjects.com/extending-crm/javascript/html-web-resources/)